# Upload file from external url to S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to S3 from an external url.

Currently, I can successfully upload a file, but after I download and open it I see that it is corrupted.

Here is the code I'm using (got is just what I use to fetch the resource):

```
const got = require('got');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
});

const response = await got('https://example.com/image.jpg');

const uploadedFile = await s3
    .upload({
        Bucket: 'my_bucket',
        Key: 'images/',
        Body: response.body,
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
    })
    .promise();
```

I tried to create a buffer, and use putObject instead of upload, but I end up with with files that are only a few bytes on S3 instead.

Comment: I think you save the file on your client first. Then write to s3.

Comment: What is the type of `response.body`?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary The response.body looks like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/P893Oc8P

Here is an example of an external image: [Link](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTjg8axD9r3FT7UVZwmGPmfYAd4wAyBhJnQhbwBqnazdC/nft.jpg)

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344 also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I have added the dependencies and S3 configuration I'm using, which is the default config, but it's the exact code I'm using.

Comment: @committer Thank you! What's the output of `console.log(typeof(response.body));`?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary It's a string.

Comment: Do `const response = got.stream('https://example.com/image.jpg');` and retry - does that work? Note it doesn't return a `Promise` so don't use `await`. Also do `Body: response`; I have to say *`got`'s documentation is some of the worst, unclear documentation I've ever had to sift through*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238150/discussion-between-ermiya-eskandary-and-committer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it through streams as mentioned by [Ermiya Eskandary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4800344/ermiya-eskandary) seems to work:

```
const response = got.stream('https://example.com/image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

The request to get the object is converting it to a string.  Pretty much whatever encoding you pick to do that will corrupt it, since a JPG is binary data not meant to be represented with an string's encoding.

The documentation for the `got` library states:

> encoding
>
> Type: `string`
>
> Default: `'utf8'`
>
> Encoding to be used on setEncoding of the response data.
>
> To get a Buffer, you need to set responseType to buffer instead. Don't set this option to null.

In other words, if you change your download to:

```js
const response = await got('https://example.com/image.jpg', {'responseType': 'buffer'});
```

You'll get and upload a Buffer object without changing it by encoding it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your key is wrong when you are uploading the file to S3:

```
Key: 'images/'
```

It cannot be `images/` because that would upload the image to an object that represents a folder. While that might work with the local file system on your Windows/Mac laptop, it doesn't work with object stores. It needs to be a key that represents a file, for example:

```
Key: 'images/image.jpg'
```